# What's a word for somebody you’ve never met?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I’m trying to think of a word for somebody I’ve never met, but who has influenced me.

Like Steve Jobs, I’ve never met him, but he continues to teach me.

He’s like an invisible hand to me.  An unmet teacher.  I can’t nail the word down!

Comment: You're saying he's a *stranger*?

Comment: The title is completely misleading. Even the question is stated in reverse.

Comment: It's actually not stated in reverse... Introduce problem, give an example, then state i can't figure it out.   Seems like the normal question to me.  Also, it's a concise title that is completely relative to my question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is also [***role model***](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/role%2Bmodel?region=us&q=role-model): *a person looked to by others as an example to be imitated.*

Answer (score 2):

While he is a stranger, he is also a *mentor*.

Comment: That implies a more direct relationship, I think

Comment: In his book *A Game Plan for Life: The Power of Mentoring*, John Wooden say how his father, coaches, President Abraham Lincoln, and Mother Theresa all had a powerful influence on his life, coaching, philosophy, and outlook on life. He  says that as individuals we can be mentored by the writings, words, and thoughts of people we have never and will likely never meet. 

Davis Lui MD, blog post on www.kevinmd.com, thanks one of his mentors, Steve Jobs. He says he has never met Steve Jobs.

It seems as though a mentor can be someone we have not met or are unlikely to meet.

Comment: The fact that John Wooden has to make that point simply proves that he is stretching the word beyond its common usage.

Comment: @SiteDesigns: That's a good comment. In the future, I'd recommend adding that sort of thing to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would use either *role model* or *mentor*.

Comment: This answer can be improved by adding citations of reputable references.

Comment: "Mentor" implies to me that it's someone you actually know personally. "Role model" seems to me the best answer here.

Answer (score 2):

Could you just go for the emotional component, and say that that man is an **inspiration**?

For my ears it's a broader word that better grabs the 'influence in some way' aspect of it all esp if you pair it with the "I've not met him" opening. For example:

> I'm trying to think of a word for somebody I've never met, but who has influenced me.
>
> Like Steve Jobs, I've never met him, but he continues to teach me.
>
> He's like an invisible hand to me. An unmet teacher. An **inspiration!**

(gratuitous exclamation mark added for effect)

Answer (score 0):

I understand the feeling and reasons that prompted you to ask. There is a vacancy in vocabulary for this particular fandom. I recoil at the thought of those people that made a point to make a comment on clearly something they are mentally unequipped to answer, yet that is not their fault.

You could stretch to refer to Latin if nothing else is quite one-the-head.

Persona Grata, perhaps.

At a long stretch in this 21st Century a reinvention of the word Amicus may have viability for such description.

I often find the best part of writing in our English language is the puzzles one must solve in order to correctly arrive at a point, emotion or purpose. Try to have fun using multiple words when one word is not enough, often one word may seem to be perfect to the speaker but quite often the audience needs more information.

My Kindred Friend.

Answer (score 0):

oracle

Perhaps not an exact match or obvious choice for this question but neither an exact match, nor an obvious choice sprang to mind.

Answer (score -4):

I know what you mean, I think.  It's elusive, though.

*Paragon*?

Comment: Seems like a good choice

Comment: Gosh, I wonder who voted that down?  Can't think at all...

Comment: Don't worry, best answer wins.

Comment: *Paragon* implies nothing whatsoever about whether you've met the person or not. In fact, I can't think of an interpretation that makes it an appropriate answer to this question.

Comment: But it's much better than, say, mentor or teacher. It's used similarly to role model, but with the added sense that they're more than just a personal inspiration, but that they exemplify the highest quality of a certain characteristic. It also carries some of the larger-than-life, admired-from-afar aspect that the OP asked for. If this person were an excellent moral compass or engineer, it would be valid to call them a paragon of morality or a paragon of engineering just as much as a role model!

Comment: While I agree with Martha, _paragon_ does not imply "never met," the way that the answerer specifically mentioned how this question was _elusive_, and then used a question mark after _paragon_, should have staved off some downvotes. Had the answer asserted more boldly, "The word that you're looking for is **paragon**," then downvoting would have been more justified, at least in my mind.

Comment: Thank you, @J.R. I'd have hoped that more people on this site would appreciate that.